# Variadic template function won't link

Tags: c++, c++11, linker-errors, variadic, template-function

cmds.cpp has this:

```
namespace TestNamespace
{
    template<typename... Args>
    void tprint(Args const& ... args)
    {
        std::ostringstream message;
        using List= int[];
        (void)List{0, ((void)(message << args), 0) ... };

        std::cout << message.str();
    }
}
```

cmds.h has this:

```
namespace TestNamespace
{
    template<typename... Args> void tprint(Args const& ... args);
}
```

main.cpp has this:

```
#include "cmds.h"

using namespace TestNamespace;

void func()
{
    tprint("test\n");
}
```

Compiler happily compiles. Linker, however, says:

```
main.cpp: undefined reference to `void TestNamespace::tprint<char [6]>(char const (&) [6])'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Makefile flags:

```
CPPFLAGS=-std=c++11 -m32 -Wall -g -I./ -Wno-trigraphs
LDFLAGS=-std=c++11 -m32 -L./ -lm
```

What is going on?

Comment: Templates have static linkage, consequently their definitions must go in the header.

Comment: Thanks. I'm quite new to using templates. (obviously, right?)
Unfortunately, having to move it to the header file throws a huge wrench into my code, which is a lot more complicated than the stripped-down version I posted.